# Depletion regime in MOS capacitor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

(I originally asked this in Electronics SE, I was redirected here as this was a better place to post my question)

I was watching a video lecture recorded by my Uni prof, where while dealing with the depletion regime in MOS Capacitors he defined the depletion regime as the regime where $\psi_S < \phi_F$, where $\psi_S$ is the surface potential wrt deep inside the body, and $\phi_F$ is equal to $(E_F - E_i)/e$. He also remarked that at $\psi_S = \phi_F$ the surface properties would resemble that of an intrinsic semiconductor, and asked us to think about it, hinting at the fact that $\psi_S = \phi_F$ would mean that the actual Fermi level and intrinsic fermi level coincide at the surface (**HOW**? I don't know, I guessed that in point 2 below)

I tried to think about it and failed to grasp it fully. I hope someone will be able to get this thing across me; meanwhile these are the points I managed to conclude:

1. When the fermi levels coincide, then the electron density at the surface becomes equal to the intrinsic carrier concentration, as $$n_{surface} = n_i\exp\bigg(\dfrac{E_F - E_i}{k_BT}\bigg)$$
2. We know, the electronic charge x (total amount of band-bending) is equal to the potential of the oxide surface wrt the body. Thus, if $\psi_S = \phi_F$ then the bands should meet at the oxide surface.